# How to pass parameters from view to controller without database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application that is making phone calls to `people`.  Each `person` has a `score` field from 1-100.

I need to dynamically set the score for my query to call people based on an administrators preference.  So an administrator can say call everyone that has a score between 0 and 25.

How would I pass those score parameters to the controller without saving anything to the database?

Comment: Whenever you pass anything from a form to the controller, you don't automatically do anything to the database.  Anything that you *do* do to the database is explicitly stated in the controller, or in a model method called by the controller.

Comment: I thought with forms you are either using them to Create or Update new/existing records.

Comment: No, they just pass some params to the controller.  You can do what you want with the params.  Often you might use them to load or update a record, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a form where the user can enter a score.  This form is submitted to the controller, which gets something like `params = {:score => 25}`.

Then in the controller you can say

```
@people = Person.where("score >= ?", params[:score])
#do something with @people, eg render a template listing their phone numbers
```

at this point, we've done a database read, but no database save.